# QML model-based components have modelData undefined on android

Tags: android, c++, qml, cross-platform

I am trying to deploy my application on Android (version 4), but I have problem with delegates in models - `ReferenceError: modelData is not defined`.

My code is

```
MapItemView {
    model: roadModel
    delegate: MapPolyline {
        line.width: 3
        line.color: "red"
        path: [
            modelData.fromWaypoint,
            modelData.toWaypoint
        ]
    }
}
```

This code should connect two points on `Map` component.

Everything works on GCC Ubuntu 16, but when I try to deploy it on Android, `modelData` just stop working and is undefined.

How can I make `modelData` work again?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is `roadModel`? As I know `modelData` is for simple models without roles. `MapItemView` supports only `QAbstractItemModel` so you should use roles instead.

Comment: `roadModel` is `QAbstractListModel` derived class

Comment: Ok, so you have to use roles. What is `modelData` in your case?

Comment: I used role name and now it works, thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`modelData` is only defined for "dumb" models, the ones without roles like a QStringList, a javascrpit array, an integer, ...
It acts like if the model had a single role named `modelData`

For `QAbstractListModel` (a custom c++ one, or a `ListModel`), the model has a list of roles, you use them to access model data in a delegate.

In your case, it should be `fromWaypoint` or with the model qualifier (`model.fromWaypoint`) if you want to avoid shadowing and be explicit.

The relevant doc is here : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#models